# How numerical radius help us to conclude an operator is normal and partial isometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

In Furuta's book, "Invitation to Linear Operators" there is a theorem, theorem 2 in 3.7.3, that says:

If $T^k=T$ for some integer $k\ge 2$ and if $w(T)\le 1$, then $T$ is the direct sum of a unitary operator and zero, that is $T$ is normal and partial isometry.

I have tried several ways to solve this but unfortunately I couldn't do that.
Since I need to proof of this theorem, I will be glad if someone could help me for it.

Comment: Can you provide a little context of the theorem, please? *(Where do the direct sum theorems start? Why considering direct sum with zero?)*

Comment: In fact this theorem is an extension of another theorem in Furuta's book, theorem 4 in 3.7.2, that says:
"If $T$ is a contraction operator and satisfies $T^k=T$ for some positive integer $k≥2$, then $T$ is normal and partial isometry."
Being contraction implies that norm of $T$ is not grater than one. We know $w(T)≤||T||$, so actuality my question is not a conclusion of this one.

Comment: Also an operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is normal and partial isometry if and only if $T$ is direct sum of a unitary operator and zero. If you need to a proof, I can explain more about it.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $p(\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda^{k-1}-1)$ has distinct roots
$$
   0,\alpha,\alpha^{2},\cdots,\alpha^{k-1},\;\;\;\; \alpha=e^{2\pi i/(k-1)}.
$$
Therefore, $X$ decomposes into the direct (not necessarily orthogonal) sum
$$
      X = M_0\oplus M_1\oplus M_2\oplus \cdots \oplus M_{k-1},\\
      M_0=\mathcal{N}(T),\;\;\;M_{j}=\mathcal{N}(T-\alpha^{j}I).
$$
In order to show that $T$ is normal on $M_1\oplus M_2\oplus\cdots\oplus M_{k-1}$, it is necessary and sufficient to show that $M_l\perp M_m$ for $l \ne m$. Let $x_l \in M_l$ and $x_m \in M_m$ be unit vectors with $l \ne m$. Then
\begin{align}
    &(T(x_l+\rho e^{i\theta}x_m),x_l+\rho e^{i\theta}x_m) \\
  & =\alpha^{l}+\rho e^{-i\theta}\alpha^{l}(x_l,x_m)+\rho e^{i\theta}\alpha^{m}(x_m,x_l)+\rho^{2}\alpha^{m} \\
  & = \alpha^{l}+\rho^{2}\alpha^{m}+\rho\alpha^{l}e^{-i\theta}(x_l,x_m)+\rho\alpha^{m}\overline{e^{-i\theta}(x_l,x_m)} \\
  & = \alpha^{l}+\rho^{2}\alpha^{m}+\alpha^{(l+m)/2}2\rho\Re(\alpha^{(l-m)/2}e^{-i\theta}(x_l,x_m)) \\
  & = \alpha^{l}\{1+2\rho\alpha^{-(l-m)/2}Re(\alpha^{(l-m)/2}e^{-i\theta}(x_l,x_m))\}+\rho^{2}\alpha^{m}.
\end{align}
Similarly,
$$
       \|x_l+\rho e^{i\theta}x_m\|^{2}=1+2\rho\Re(e^{-i\theta}(x_l,x_m))+\rho^{2}
$$
Choose $\theta$ so that $\Re(e^{-i\theta}(x_l,x_m))=0$, which is the same as choosing $\theta$ so that
$$
    e^{-i\theta}(x_l,x_m)=\pm i|(x_l,x_m)|.
$$
Then, ignoring $\rho^{2}$ terms (thinking of $\rho$ as small):
$$
     \frac{(T(x_l+\rho e^{i\theta}x_m),x_l+\rho e^{i\theta}x_m)}{\|x_l+\rho e^{i\theta}x_m\|^{2}}\approx \alpha^{l}\left(1\pm 2\rho \alpha^{-(l-m)/2}\Im(\alpha^{(l-m)/2})|(x_l,x_m)|\right).
$$
The right side can be shown to be greater than 1 in magnitude by choosing $\pm$, if necessary, unless $(x_l,x_m)=0$ or unless $\alpha^{(l-m)/2}=\pm 1$. So $(x_l,x_m)=0$.

Comment: It is easy to show that  $X=M_0\oplus\cdots\oplus M_{k-1}$ when all the elements in the spectrum are eigenvalues, but I don't think such decomposition holds in general.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : I'm assuming everything here is over the complex numbers because discussions of normal imply it. Assuming we're working over $\mathbb{C}$, yes, there is always such a decomposition where $M_{j}=\mathcal{N}((T-\lambda_j I)^{r_j})$ and $r_j$ is the power appearing in the minimal polynomial. In the case here, where $M_{0}=\mathcal{N}(T)$, the power is $1$ because the minimal polynomial must have power 1 for the root of $0$. This is the Jordan decomposition.

Comment: What hypothesis over $T$ guarantees such decomposition? The proof I know of the Jordan Decomposition uses that the elements of the spectrum are eigenvalues.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : Over the complex numbers, the minimal polynomial factors completely, and that makes the Jordan form work. The Jordan decomposition exists for all linear operators on finite-dimensional complex linear spaces.

Comment: Yes, but in this question the operators are not necessarily acting on a finite-dimensional space. I still don't see how you prove the existence of the Jordan form for an arbitrary operator acting on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : You get the decomposition from the existence of a minimal polynomial, finite-dimensional or not. I was careful about how I stated that. And, in this case, the roots are simple, which makes the proof is very straightforward.